# How to get Mongoose findById response inside a map function of lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, lodash

I have an array with ids and I need to look for those IDs in a collection called Users (collection and model exists) to get information about the user with that id.

```
    var emails = _.map(toSendEmails,function(id){
        var userEmail = User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            return user.email;
        });

        return userEmail;
    });
```

Variable toSendEmails is a arrays of ids.

Actual scenario is that the map function executes before User.findById returns any value

How should I proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can return an array of promises from the `_.map` function and wait for all of theses promises to get resolved to get a list of emails.

```
var ePromises = _.map(toSendEmails,function(id){
    return User.findById(id).then(function (user) {
        return user.email;
    });
});

Promise.all(ePromises).then( function (emails){
    // do something with the emails
});
```

Comment: Thanks! ePromises is an array of promises that I can now use with Promises.all

Answer (score 1):

While someone will surely come along soon to tell you to use Promise.all, the easiest thing for you would be to just use the (async)[https://www.npmjs.com/package/async] library from npm, it has a map function identical to lodash that handles the call back flow for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by using **async/await**.

```
var emails = _.map(toSendEmails, async function(id){
    var user = await User.findById(id);
    return user.email
});
```

Comment: Could you explain this?

Comment: in mongoose User.findById will return promise and by await keyword it will wait for promise resolve and return to map function.